# How do you generate and update plot using python for intermetently generated values

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Barplot]

I am using the below codes to generate and update the bar plot using python pandas in real time scenario.I need and updated bar plot in a single window.Please run Tank_001.py file and I need a single window updated bar plot as shown in the attachment.The output I am getting here is an intermittent ones and not the consolidated ones.Could anyone help me in this.

```
#Classdef Tank_002
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Tank:

   def __init__(self, DATE, INITIAL_VALUE,INFLOW,DISCHARGE,NET_QUANTITY):
        self.DATE = DATE
        self.INFLOW = INFLOW
        self.DISCHARGE = DISCHARGE
        self.NET_QUANTITY = INITIAL_VALUE

   def Discharge(self,DATE,DISCHARGE):
        self.DATE = DATE
        self.DISCHARGE = DISCHARGE
        self.NET_QUANTITY -= DISCHARGE

   def Inflow(self,DATE,INFLOW):
        self.DATE = DATE
        self.INFLOW = INFLOW
        self.NET_QUANTITY += INFLOW

   def dump(self):
        s =  (self.DATE,self.INFLOW, self.DISCHARGE,self.NET_QUANTITY)
        z =  [(s[0],s[3])]
        print z
        labels,ys =zip(*z)
        xs=np.arange(len(labels))
        width = 1
        plt.bar(xs, ys, width, align='center')
        plt.xticks(xs, labels) 
        plt.yticks(ys)
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()

##Tank_002.py

from Classdef_Tank_002 import Tank
print ' '             
p1=Tank('01/10/2018',1000,0,0,0)#Initial Value
p1.dump()
print ' '               
p1.Discharge('02/10/2018',500)#Discharge
p1.dump()
print ' '            
p1.Inflow('03/10/2018',300)#Inflow
p1.dump()
print ' ' 
p1.Inflow('04/10/2018',300)#Inflow
p1.dump()
print ' '
```

Comment: Looks like a fun project. Why don't you try to minimize the code and display only the relevant parts.

Comment: Please run the second file Tank_001.py

Comment: Please run the second file Tank_002.py for the results.

Comment: I need all the bar values plotted in one single window at once and not in series as this is one.